# How can I add an "unsupported" permission to my Expo React Native app?

Tags: android, expo, react-native

I am trying to add the permission `com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM` to my app. This permission is not explicitly supported according to the [expo docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions).

I have tried adding it to app.json:

```
"android": {
  "permissions": [
    "com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"
  ]
},
```

I have also tried just asking in code (notice I have to cast the string since this permission is “unsupported”):

```
const ALARM_PERMISSION = 'com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM' as PermissionType

const [permission] = usePermissions(ALARM_PERMISSION, {ask: true, get: false})
```

But nothing seems to work. Am I doomed to eject my otherwise simple app so that I can add this permission directly to the manifest?

EDIT:

I am trying to launch the `SET_ALARM` intent using the following code, which returns the error below.

```
IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(ACTION_SET_ALARM)
```

> Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method startActivity on module ExpoIntentLauncher: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.SET_ALARM cmp=com.google.android.deskclock/com.android.deskclock.HandleSetApiCalls } from ProcessRecord{cd38534 14798:host.exp.exponent/u0a355} (pid=14798, uid=10355) requires com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM

Comment: what would you do with this permission if you didn't eject? there is no api available for setting an alarm in the managed workflow currently, so even if you had the permission it would not matter, as far as i know.

Comment: I am using [expo-intent-launcher](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/intent-launcher/) to fire off `SET_ALARM`.  See my edit above for the code and error I'm getting.